# Der komplexe Satz mit Attributsatz und "und"

Tags: grammar-identification, subordinate-clause

I have following sentence:

> Es war einmal ein richtiger Student, der in einer Dachkammer wohnte und nichts besaß.

How many sentences do we have in this sentence?  I know that Hauptsatz in this sentence is

> Es war einmal ein richtiger Student

but I don't understand what is from the grammatical point of view the second part

> der in einer Dachkammer wohnte und nichts besaß

I think that here we have two Nebensätzes:

- Nebensatz 1: der in einer Dachkammer wohnte
- Nebensatz 2: und nichts besaß

I think that Nebensatz 1 is an Attributsatz. What is the second Nebensatz? Is it also another Attributsatz or what? I will be thankful for any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both of them are relative subclauses which were joined by the coordinating conjunction "und" into one single relative subclause.

This means that these individual subclauses share the same grammatical order and therefore can be coordinated by a conjunction like "und" to form only one subclause which then, as a whole, would function like the individual ones on their own.

Accordingly, this joined relative subclause could be divided again into its respective syntactic components:

> Es war einmal ein richtiger Student, der in einer Dachkammer wohnte und nichts besaß.

comprises the same as

> Es war einmal ein richtiger Student, der in einer Dachkammer wohnte. Es war einmal ein richtiger Student, der nichts besaß.

Comment: So it means that both Nebensätzes are Attributsätzes, yes?

Comment: Attributivsätze as in modifying clauses, yes.

Answer (score 0):

*"How many sentences do we have in this sentence?"* - In the deep structure we've got three, and they're all main clauses.

> 1) Es war einmal ein richtiger Student.
>
> 2) Der Student wohnte in einer Dachkammer.
>
> 3) Der Student besaß nichts.

In the transformation, 1) remains a main clause, 2) and 3) are being transformed to relative clauses and linked by *und*. We first get:

> Es war einmal ein richtiger Student, der in einer Dachkammer wohnte und der nichts besaß.

The 2nd *der* is being tilted, and we get:

> Es war einmal ein richtiger Student, der in einer Dachkammer wohnte und nichts besaß.